# Workflow Call HTTP Web Service Get Information From External Site

Tags: workflow, web-services

this my first attempt using the Call Web Service feature. I am trying to use a SharePoint workflow to get information from BMC Remedy (a help desk ticketing system) and have it put into a SharePoint list.

I would like to know if this is possible and if so how can it be done?

Thank you for reading